# Lists and columns in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to take number inputs from user and add them into a 2 dimensional list and do add the third column together.

```
Sample Run:

Enter 3 numbers: 1 2 9
Enter 3 numbers: 3 4 9
Enter 3 numbers: 9 1 1
Enter 3 numbers:


1 2 9
3 4 9
9 1 1

column 3 total = 19
```

This is what I have so far

```
def main():
  string = input("Enter 3 numbers: ")
  lst = string.split()
  lst = [int(a) for a in lst]
  while string != '':
    string = input("Enter 3 numbers: ")
    lst2 = string.split()
    lst.append([int(a) for a in lst2])
  print(lst)
main()
```

How do I display my numbers now like in the sample and add only third column together

Comment: You're overwriting the list each time you run the loop.

Comment: Can you explain? This was the only way that I could get the inputed numbers such as 1 2 9 into integers in a list. If I just did int(input) before everything I got an error. @MorganThrapp

Comment: @Sam There's nothing wrong with how you're forming the list. You could even combine it into a single `lst = [int(a) for a in string.split()]`. But each run of the `while` loop you overwrite your old `lst` with the newest version, losing the older input data.

Comment: So should I create a new variable each time? If so how would I do that if I don't know how many new variables I would need?@Two-BitAlchemist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep overwriting `lst`. But there is a bigger problem. You need an outer list to hold the user input lists.

```
def main():
    array = []
    string = input("Enter 3 numbers: ")
    lst = string.split()
    lst = [int(a) for a in lst]
    array.append(lst)
    while string != '':
        string = input("Enter 3 numbers: ")
        lst = string.split()
        array.append([int(a) for a in lst])
    print(array)
main()
```

Your code would be a bit cleaner if you combined the prompts into a single while loop

```
def main():
    lst = []
    while True:
        data = input("Enter 3 numbers: ")
        if not data:
            break
        lst.append([int(a) for a in data.split()])
    print lst
    # to get more output....
    for row in lst:
        print('{} {} {}'.format(*row))
    print('column 3 sum is {}'.format(sum(row[2] for row in lst)))
main()
```

A sample run of the second example

```
$ python3 x.py
Enter 3 numbers: 1 2 3
Enter 3 numbers: 4 5 6
Enter 3 numbers: 7 8 9
Enter 3 numbers: 
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Not quite... and the problem shows a bug in my example too. You want an outer list holding an inner list per row. The `+=` extends `lst` with each element of `lst2` instead of just appending the list. I'' update my answer it fix it for both of us.

Comment: Thanks that seemed to be what I was looking for but how do I now make the numbers neat to where it prints like the sample run, right now they are just one continuous list. Do I just get the position after every 3rd number and make a new line? @tdelaney

Comment: @sam my first example was buggy but the second should work. I'll add example output.

Comment: So this is what I was looking for and what my professor told me to do. Im trying to work through this step by step. Do you see how in my sample run at the top it is displaying every set of 3 on a new line how do I do that? My professor told me to use your output to get to there@tdelaney

Comment: And to add the columns together is there a call function that allows me to select like every third position and add them together

Comment: You can use a "list comprehension" to get the values of a columm... `col3 = [row[2] for row in lst]` and you can shortcut the sum with `col3sum = sum(row[2] for row in lst)`. As for printing the row, use a `for` loop and as you get each row, do `print('{} {} {}'.format(*row))`.

Comment: If you do the col3sum its just giving me the sum of the last input line so it would be 0 since it was a blank line@tdelaney

Comment: I was working off of my second example where `lst` is the outer list of rows. If you run that example, it'll display the proper stuff for you.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and working through this with me step by step. I actually understand exactly why we did certain things and not others@tdelaney